# document.getElementById().src audio issue

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio, getelementbyid, src

What am I doing wrong here? (see JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/55aJt/6/)

```
<audio id="myAudio" src="" controls></audio>
```

Object

```
var allQuestions = [{
    question: "http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3",
    choices: ["3rd", "5th", "4th"],
    correctAnswer: 2
},
```

Function

```
function setHeader(questionNum) {
    var questionHeaderEl = document.getElementById("myAudio").src;
    questionHeaderEl.innerHTML = allQuestions[questionNum].question;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var questionHeaderEl = document.getElementById("myAudio").src;
questionHeaderEl.innerHTML = allQuestions[questionNum].question;
```

with above code you are creating a `var` for element's `src` value then you are trying change `innerHtml` of that `src` value. It should be like this:

```
var questionHeaderEl = document.getElementById("myAudio");
questionHeaderEl.src = allQuestions[questionNum].question;
```

Comment: Eureka! This is perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
questionHeaderEl.src
```

instead of

```
questionHeaderEl.innerHTML
```